# Deserializing with JSON.NET - all members set to default value

Tags: c#, json.net, deserialization

I have the following JSON:

```
{
"Texture": "Sprites\\wall.png",
"Rect": null,
"Rotation": 0,
"Hitbox": [-25, -25, 50, 50],
"PositionChange": [0, 0]
}
```

Which I'm trying to deserialize to this class:

```
class SimpleEntityFrame
{
    [JsonConverter(typeof(TextureConverter))]
    public Texture Texture { get; private set; }

    [JsonConverter(typeof(IntRectConverter))]
    public IntRect? Rect { get; private set; }

    public float Rotation { get; private set; }

    [JsonConverter(typeof(FloatRectConverter))]
    public FloatRect? Hitbox { get; private set; }

    [JsonConverter(typeof(Vector2fConverter))]
    public Vector2f PositionChange { get; private set; }
}
```

Like so:

```
var simpleEntityFrames = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SimpleEntityFrame>(File.ReadAllText("Data\\SimpleEntities.json"));
```

When I do this, though, I'm getting back a SimpleEntityFrame in its default state - all reference members set to null and all value members to zero. I know the CustomCreationConverters I'm using work fine as I use them to deserialize into another class too. I know I could solve this by making a CustomCreationConverter for my SimpleEntityFrame class, but I can't see why this should be necessary in this case. What am I missing?

Comment: Have you tried adding `DataContract` and `DataMember` attributes? Doing that, along with using a POCO containing those attributes for an actual type for the conversion to use has worked nicely for me.

Comment: @ChristopherStevenson Yeah, that's made it work - thanks! I'm a little confused as to why I've never needed those attributes before - what exactly do they communicate to the parser?

Comment: Without those serialization attributes, Json.NET has to guess how you want to turn the JSON into an object. Sometimes it guesses badly.